# Ubuntu php upgrading issue

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, php

I have a problem after I updated my php version to 5.6 from 5.5.

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu).
PHP version: 5.5.
Laravel 4.2 with yajra package.
```

I have done the following steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppandrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After that, I checked whether oci8 extension exists or not:

```
cat /etc/php5/cli/php.ini | grep extension=oci8 => exists
cat /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini | grep extension=oci8 => exists
```

But the following error was occurred when I load my web on the browser:

```
2017-01-09 20:13:54] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined function Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()' in /var/www/****/vendor/yajra/laravel-pdo-via-oci8/src/Pdo/Oci8.php:449
```

How to solve this problem? Is there any idea, please...